# Ebay AddItem Api Call for video game consoles category call error

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I am new in eBay API integration. I want to add product for video game and consoles category.
I am call firstly VerifyAddItem for video game and console category
But i got error in eBay VerifyAddItem API call

Here is error-

This listing should contain product details from the eBay catalog. Add product details to this listing

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VerifyAddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>abcd</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <Item>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>139971</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <ItemSpecifics>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Brand</Name><Value>SONY</Value></NameValueList><NameValueList>
                <Name>MPN</Name><Value>Does not apply</Value></NameValueList>
        </ItemSpecifics>
        <PictureDetails>
            <PictureURL>https://demo.com/Penguins.jpg</PictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <DispatchTimeMax>1</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ListingDuration>Days_30</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
        <Location><![CDATA[Koln]]></Location>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>abc@gmail.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <RegionID>77</RegionID>
        <StartPrice>20</StartPrice>
        <ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>
        <Title><![CDATA[White Knight Chronicles Original PS3 Game BRAND NEW SEALED]]></Title>
        <Description><![CDATA[White Knight Chronicles Original PS3 Game BRAND NEW SEALED<br>]]></Description>
        <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ShippingServiceOptions><ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
            <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0</ShippingServiceCost>
            <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
            <ShippingService>Other</ShippingService></ShippingServiceOptions>
        </ShippingDetails>
    </Item>
</VerifyAddItemRequest>
```

How to resolve this error And add product for video game and console category with brand name.